# SwiftUI Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SessionStore found

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm creating a SwiftUI app that includes Firebase to enable logging into an account, extremely simple. But when i run this code, the following error "SwiftUI Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SessionStore found." pops up when calling session.session, can you tell me where the error is in this code ? Thank's guys

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    func getUser () {
        session.listen()
     }
    
    var body: some View{
            VStack {
                if session.session != nil {
                    LoginView()
                }
                else{
                    TabView {
                        ProfilView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Profil", systemImage: "person")
                            }
                        
                        NotificationsView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Notifications", systemImage: "bell")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: getUser)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore())
    }
}
```

Here The SessionStore model :

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import Firebase

final class User {
    @Published var uid: String
//    var email: String?
    @Published var displayName: String?

    init(uid: String, displayName: String?) {
        self.uid = uid
//        self.email = email
        self.displayName = displayName
    }

}

final class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    
   @Published var session: User?
   @Published var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

   func listen () {
       // monitor authentication changes using firebase
       handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
           if let user = user {
               // if we have a user, create a new user model
               print("Got user: \(user)")
               self.session = User(
                   uid: user.uid,
                   displayName: user.displayName
               )
           } else {
               // if we don't have a user, set our session to nil
               self.session = nil
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to add SessionStore as an EnvironmentObject.

Comment: Show where you initialize `ContentView()` -- it needs to have `.environmentObject()` on it with the session storage

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx 

Comment: @jnpdx It looks like your information fixed the problem, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to include `.environmentObject(SessionStore())` wherever you instantiate `ContentView`:

```
ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore())
```

This needs to happen anywhere `ContentView` is used (eg in the previews and the actual app hierarchy itself, such as coming from `SceneDelegate` or the `WindowGroup` if you're using the SwiftUI view lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue today but jnpdx last sentence was essential:

This needs to happen anywhere ContentView is used (eg in the previews and the actual app hierarchy itself...)